# Define function's argument in terminal by user in R

Tags: r, function, terminal, readline

I have a function with single argument

```
define <- function(x) {...}
```

now I want to use readline function to let user define this argument itself in terminal
I tried the following code but it does not work:

```
data <- define(readline(prompt = "Please enter Code: "))
```

Comment: What do you mean 'it doesn't work'? If, for example the body of `define` is `{ return(as.numeric(x) - 1)}` then the code works as expected, and you get a prompt. If you enter `3` at the prompt then the value `2` is stored in `data`. What are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

I defined a simple function:

```
define <- function(x) {
  y = as.numeric(x) + 1
  return(y)
}
```

When you ask the user to set a value for example 3, the output looks like this:

```
data <- define(readline(prompt = "Please enter Code: "))
data

Please enter Code: 3
> data
[1] 4
```

As you can see, the code does its job.

#### Edit for you comment:

You can add a `menu` to give user a choice like this:

```
define <- function(x) {
  choice <- menu(c("Tc","Tr","Ty","Mn"))
  return(choice)
}

data <- define(readline(prompt = "Please enter corresponding number: "))
```

Which looks like this:

```
> data <- define(readline(prompt = "Please enter corresponding number: "))

1: Tc
2: Tr
3: Ty
4: Mn

Selection: Tc
> data
[1] 1
```

Comment: Is is possible to implement menu() function in readline to let R users chose pre-specified argument from list? For instance  menu(c("Tc","Tr","Ty","Mn"), title="Please enter  corresponding number: ")

Comment: @JohnOsh, Yes you can add a `menu` in your function. I added the code to my answer above.

Comment: thank you, but when I select for instance 3, "ty" must be put as argument instead of x in the function I created. (full code of function is not given here but the general idea is to let user select argument from menu)

Answer (score 0):

```
define <- function(x) {
data <- define(readline(prompt = "Please enter Code: "))
data <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(data, ",")))
return(data)

}
```

Is it something like this you ask?

Comment: Is is possible to implement menu() function into readline to let R users chose pre-specified argument from list? For instance  menu(c("Tc","Tr","Ty","Mn"), title="Please enter  corresponding number: ")